# vba Change event when data validation selected

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a workbook that in Column C there is data validation drop down list. I'm tryinto code so that when a specific status is selected in the drown down (i.e. "Verification") Column I will automatically enter "Verification Unprocessed". Column I also has data validation and a drop down list. I've searched all over and can't seem to find a code that identifies a worksheet change event from a data validation drop down list. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You fact that you have a drop-down list is not important. The Worksheet Change event will fire regardless of how the cell is changed. All you need to do is check if the `Target` variable in the event is in the right column, then do what you need to do. Sample code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Target
        If .Count = 1 Then
            If .Row > 1 And .Column = 3 Then
                If .Value = "specific status" Then
                    .Offset(0, 6).Value = "Verification Unprocessed"
                Else
                    .Offset(0, 6).ClearContents
                End If
            ElseIf .Column = 5 Then
                If .Value = Date Then
                   Call Lilly
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Let me know if you need further information.

EDIT: Incorperated your original code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That didn't work though. I entered it exactly and just changed the specific status to "verification" selected that drop down and nothing happened.

Comment: I put the code in the worksheet for the specific worksheet that I'm making the change. Oh, not sure if this matters, but I already have a code in there for a change event for a different column that has to do with date. That code works perfectly, but I'm not sure if there is allowed to be two change events.

Comment: That would be the problem. You'll need to incorperate the above code into your existing worksheet change event.

Comment: Okay this is the code I currently have. How would I add it? Just paste it under, before the End sub? I entered the code above under your comment by accident.

Comment: You would simply add a `ElseIf` to the `If` statement we used to get `Target`'s column. I edited my answer to include the code you posted.

Comment: I have a question, I'm incorporating your code, but I have multiple "statuses" which ever "status" is entered it'll always be "Verification Unprocessed" but how would I incorporate the different statuses?